# LU factorization of a modify matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose you know $L$, $U$, decomposition LU of a matrix $M+I$ ($M+I=LU$). Lets $J$ a diagonal matrix whose elements are $0$ or $1$.

Is there any relation between the factorization LU of $M+I$, and the factorization LU of $JM+I$ ?

Thanks.